# is JXTA 2.7 production ready and when is Chaupal 1.0 due?

Tags: p2p, jxta

i am about to develop a new application and I was looking at JXSE framework. It seems some political issues with oracle have killed the project from what i understand. this raises a few questions:

1. Is JXSE 2.7 stable enough for production use?
2. Will jXSE/JXTA for java still be developed?
3. is Chaupal the continuation of JXSE (does it start from the 2.7 codebase?)
4. when is Chaupal 1.0 set for release? (approximation i guess)
5. how similar will Chaupal interfaces be with JXSE (how easy will it be to migrate to)

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Political issues did not kill the project. Some people are still posting patches, but it surely slowed down involvement.

> Is JXSE 2.7 stable enough for
>   production use?

Yes, some companies are even using the 2.6 branch.

> Will jXSE/JXTA for java still be
>   developed?

Some people are posting patches on the 2.6.x branch and these will be re-integrated in trunk somewhere down the road. The future of JXTA depends on voluntary contributions.

> is Chaupal the continuation of JXSE
>   (does it start from the 2.7 codebase?)

Yes and no. No, it does start from the 2.7 codebase, it starts from scratch. Yes, it is a continuation 'in spirit' of the development of an open source java based P2P library.

> when is Chaupal 1.0 set for release?
>   (approximation i guess)

No plan for a date. We are working on our spare time. So it is not fast.

> how similar will Chaupal interfaces be with JXSE (how easy will it be to migrate to)

Chaupal aims at being simpler and more straight forward. One of the weaknesses of JXTA was its complicated API. We want to solve this issue. We also want to focus more on communication between peers and drop the service loading features of JXTA.

**Update (August 2013):** You thought JXTA/JXSE was dead? Well someone worked further on it and developed a DZone tutorial (unfortunately, SO does not allow links to Dzone, so Google: JXSE and Equinox Tutorial).

Comment: Thanks, really is a good idea to focus on simplicity and performance (binary messages where optimal). Chaupal will be quite interesting, definitively looking forward to it.

Comment: That **is** a great idea. I'm currently looking at using JXTA and it takes some time and pain to wrap my head around it (-.